# How can I produce a 9 channel audio file encoded using AAC from 9 (mono) input files?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac, m4a

I'd like to create an AAC encoded audio file with an MP4 container that has a large number of channels, ideally up to 64.

I'm running something like this (but with 9 files and a larger list at the start of the filter):

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i 0.wav -i 1.wav -filter_complex '[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=9[aout]' -map '[aout]' '-c:a' aac 'multichannel.m4a'`

Unfortunately the codec complains about 9 being an unsupported number of channels. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the native AAC encoder, you can only do 1-8 or 16 channels. So, if you are bound by 9 channels, you can use 16 channels and fill the unused channels with zeros. Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 0.wav -i 1.wav \
  -filter_complex \
    'aevalsrc='0|0|0|0|0|0|0'[anull];\
     [0:a][1:a][anull]amerge=inputs=3[aout]' \
  -map [aout] -shortest -c:a aac 'out.m4a'"
```

I've tested up to 100 channels, so nothing more than 16 (well short of your target 64). Can you just put theses channels in different streams? For example, 4 streams of 16 channels each. You cannot play them back together, but there probably isn't a need to do so maybe?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) aac can support up to 48 channels. So you can try to get your hands on [Fraunhofer FDK AAC enabled FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) to see if you have a better luck.